# smtp not working for G suit accounts

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer, google-workspace

```
 require 'send/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


  $mail = new PHPMailer();


//Enable SMTP debugging.

  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.

  $mail->isSMTP();

//Set SMTP host name

  $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email

  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Provide username and password

  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Provide username and password

  $mail->Username = "admin@admin.com";

  $mail->Password = "a23k234tbk";

//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it

  $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";


//Set TCP port to connect to

  $mail->Port = 587;

  $mail->From = "admin@admin.com";

  $mail->FromName = "dummy.com";

  $mail->addAddress($user_email);

  $mail->isHTML();

  $mail->Subject = "dummy";

  $mail->Body = $table4 ? $table4 :"";



if($mail->send())
{

  header("Location:email_user.php?result=success");
  echo "";
}
else
{

  echo '';
}
}
```

So my question is; is their additional configuration that should be done for G suit gmail accounts.

the code works fine the problem only happens when i use a different "from account". When using a normal gmail account like ***@gmail.com it works but it fails when using G suit account like ***@yourdomainname.com.

Comment: So, what error message do you get? _"Not working"_ isn't really a description.

Comment: is it a google domain account?

Comment: You should probably also change `$mail->SMTPDebug` to `2` instead of `0`. Then you'll see what the SMTP servers response is. Giving us that will be vastly better than just _"not working"_ and _"failing"_.

Comment: First of all thank you for your suggestions.

**Error that I am having are:**                                     
2018-06-27 09:26:57 CLIENT -> SERVER: MTMjTGxha3NoYXk=
SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at

2018-06-27 09:26:58 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection f123-v6sm6816144pfc.4 - gsmtp
2018-06-27 09:26:58 SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: Follow the link in the error message, and read the troubleshooting guide. You're using an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). You should change your password too.